# igraph goes to the very edge of the bounding box

Tags: python, igraph

I'm going through the igraph examples in python, and keep encountering this problem.

[image: Kautz, zealously cropped]

The outermost vertices are partially outside of the bounding box. The [example](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/screenshots2.html) doesn't have this problem nearly as badly.

(Also, in mine, it seems to be drawing additional lines for two-way connections, whereas in the example, it's just putting an arrow on each side. If this is an easy fix, please let me know.)

My code, copied from the example page, is below.

```
g = Graph.Kautz(m=3, n=2)
adj = g.get_adjacency()
fig.add(g, layout="fr", vertex_label=None)
fig.add(adj, bbox=(360, 0, 480, 120), grid_width=0, opacity=0.7)
fig.show()
```

My installation details are here.

```
No configuration file, using defaults
igraph 0.6 running inside Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:16:07) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
```

I'd be very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Curved edges were introduced into the graph drawer of igraph later than the time when that figure was made in the documentation, so that's why you haven't seen the curved edges in the figure of the documentation. Anyway, curved edges can easily be disabled:

```
graph.es["curved"] = False
```

or

```
plot(graph, edge_curved=False)
```

As for the edges that do not fit in the bounding box: the `plot()` function (which is the one-shot function for quick plots) has a `margin` keyword argument that puts a white margin around the graph plot; this is essentially done by contracting the bounding box of the figure by a given number of pixels to ensure that the edges stay inside (most of the time). When you construct your own plot by working directly with the `plot` class, you have to add a margin yourself:

```
bbox = BoundingBox(600, 600)
figure = Plot(bbox=bbox)
bbox = bbox.contract(20)
figure.add(graph, bbox=bbox, layout=layout)
figure.show()
```

Another difference between the built-in `plot` function and the `Plot` class is that the `plot` function adds a white background by default, while `Plot` uses a transparent background. You can override that by using the `background` keyword argument of the `Plot` constructor.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is much more information than I had gathered, (which was by pure luck.)

Comment: Hey @Tamás, is there a compiled list of all the vertex and edge attributes that you can set? I was looking for this in the docs but couldn't find it anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: `help(Graph.__plot__)` should have a complete list of them. The reason why it is in `Graph.__plot__` is that `plot()` is just a generic plotting function that delegates plotting to the `__plot__` method of whatever object is being plotted.

Answer (score 3):

I've discovered *a* solution, after a lengthy day of documentation searching. What I'm now using is

```
graph.layout().fit_into(bbox=(<size>, <size>))
```

and, rather than using igraph.Plot(), and plot.add(graph),

```
igraph.plot(graph, bbox=(<size>, <size>))
```

Additionally, I solved my problem with curved edges.

```
graph.es["curved"] = 0
```

Thanks, everyone who looked at this, and I hope my experience helps!